# JSON object array return undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-apps-script

I have below scripts on Google Apps Script which will take in an JSON event.
I want the data in element "events", but it always return "Undefined" to me.

I'm guessing maybe it's because events is a JSON array and I can't directly use it in JS?

Here is my code:

```
function doPost(e) {
  var msg = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e.postData.contents));
  
  console.log(msg);
  //log succesfully

  console.log(msg.events);
  //"Undefined"
}
```

If I try to log the elements in the events instead of the array events itself:

```
  console.log(msg.events[0].replyToken);
  //"TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at doPost(app:26:25)"
```

The result of msg will is in below:

```
{
  "destination": "U656de3c6b48c8e0d44edda4fd3f05e06",
  "events": [
    {
      "type": "message",
      "message": {
        "type": "text",
        "id": "*********",
        "text": "Hi"
      },
      "timestamp": 1642616050062,
      "source": {
        "type": "group",
        "groupId": "***********",
        "userId": "*************"
      },
      "replyToken": "************",
      "mode": "active"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've seen several similar problems for array in JS.
I tried them but all of them didn't work, please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the result your getting from your API as `e.postData.contents` **is** a JSON string.

In this case something like this:

```
var msg = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e.postData.contents));
```

would first try to turn something into a JSON string (`JSON.stringify`) and then converting it into a JavaScript object by `JSON.parse`. In other words the JSON.stringify is useless.

Try this instead:

```
var msg = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
```

Comment: OMG! Thank you! It worked!
I had a "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 at doPost" error, so I add stringify.
I didn't expect it will cause problem....

Comment: No problem - glad I could help! =) By the way, if you think this is the correct answer please consider accepting it using the tick button.

Answer (score 0):

If the value from "e.postData.contents" is already a string, you don't have to do JSON.stringify.
If you do JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(any string) it results in adding backslash" to the values. For example

```
let str = '{name: "John"}';
let myJSON = JSON.stringify(str);
```

myJSON = "{name: "John"}"

So, please make sure "e.postData.contents" is not a string.